# More than one action for a JQuery selector

Tags: jquery

I need to set both a css property and the html contents of a class using JQuery on a PHP web page.  Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
$('.myclass').css('color','#900');
$('.myclass').html('invalid');
```

My IDE (PHPStorm) informs me that I have a duplicate JQuery selector.

How else does one write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery, you can chain methods since it almost always return a jQuery object.

So, with you current piece of code, you could do something like that :

```
$('.myclass').css('color','#900').html('invalid');
```

There is cases though that you can't chain methods since you need additional variable. In those cases, you need to cache the jQuery object in a variable. Something like this :

```
var $el = $('.myclass');

$el.css('color','#900');
var t = 'invalid';
$el.html(t);
```

Note that since the methods return a jQuery object, you can call the first one while caching the var :

```
var $el = $('.myclass').css('color','#900');
var t = 'invalid';
$el.html(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myclass').css('color','#900').html('invalid');
```

Look into [jQuery method chaining](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery works with chained functions like this. This will improve the DOM search engine.

```
$('.myclass').css('color','#900').html("invalid");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a warning or an error? That should be fine, but it's just not efficient since the browser is searching for all those class elements twice.

So ideally you'd write it as:

```
 $('.myclass').css('color', '#900').html('invalid');
```

Here's a good article on writing more efficient selectors.

http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/